# How to add username or change password in vsftpd in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

I have gotten access to a server which is configured by another person and I am now at the point where I am not able to access through ftp due to the fact that I do not have the ftp username and password and I cannot seem to be able to find or add a new username and password to the specific directory.

Please help me add username or change password in vsftpd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `vsftpd` users are the ones of the system. So if you have admin access, `root` user or a sudoer, you can log in, view the users using `getent passwd` command and `passwd SomeUser` as root to change her/his password.
`adduser SomeName` to add a user.

Check also for virtual users for `vsftpd`. Inside `vsftpd.conf` file search for something like:
`pam_service_name=`
and then locate this file name inside `/etc/pam.d/`

In case PAM mechanism is confusing you, a good indication of virtual users is   `virtual_use_local_privs=`
inside `vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: I have a vsftpd.userlist in my /etc which has one username user1 inside it however upon changing the password of this user ( which by the way exists ) I still cannot login to my ftp as I get 530 Login incorrect.

Comment: Make a backup of `vsftpd.userlist` and then try `htpasswd /etc/vsftpd.userlist user1`. If that doesn't work restore the file and have a look at this:  http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/  You need to check vsftpd.conf carefully to fully understand the setup. Virtual users' passwords are stored hashed in a file the admin makes, you need to locate it. Also it may be a case where an admin made both a system and a virtual user using the same name.